# how do i find the length of options in a combo box

Tags: javascript, jquery, combobox

How can i know is there any options in a combobox/selectbox or not?

small Edit:

i have my comboxbox as 
myCombo = $("#country");

now i want to know how many options are there in myCombo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(myCombo).children("option").length

Answer (score 2):

In jQuery:

```
if($('select#something option').length > 0) {
    // There are some.
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`length`](http://api.jquery.com/length/) property like this:

```
alert($('#dropdown_id option').length);
```

Make sure to wrap your code in ready handler:

```
$(function(){
  alert($('#dropdown_id option').length);
});
```

You can also use the [`size()`](http://api.jquery.com/size/) method:

```
$(function(){
  alert($('#dropdown_id option').size());
});
```

Comment: You mean `#dropdown_id option`, I think -- `option` is a tag, not a pseudoselector.

Answer (score 0):

```
<select id="mySelect">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
</select>
```

Then:

```
alert($('#mySelect > option').size()); //4
```

Comment: from [the API](http://api.jquery.com/size/): "You should use the .length property instead, which is slightly faster."